# Perl query and get column name

Tags: mysql, perl

I need to make a query where I will be looking for a specific string through several columns and I need to know which column (name) contains the value that I need.

In the example below I need a query where I can ask which column contains the value 1000000000002101214 and that it returns f1. DB is MySQL and I need the programming to be done in Perl.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| f1                  | f2                  | f3                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1000000000002101214 | 1000000000001989129 | 1000000000001881637 |
| 1000000000002080453 | 1000000000001968481 | 1000000000001862284 |
| 1000000000002085919 | 1000000000001973677 | 1000000000001866854 |
| 1000000000002075076 | 1000000000001963189 | 1000000000001857288 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I was able to find an almost-answer to my question from another site where I could get the column names of the fields in the table with the following:

```
my @cols = @{$sth->{NAME}}; # or NAME_lc if needed 

while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print "@row\n";
}
$sth->finish;

foreach ( @cols ) {
    printf( "Note: col : %s\n", $_ );
}
```

The problem is partially resolved. In the example table I provided in the original question I needed to know on which column my answer resides, the query contains several OR statemens:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (f1='1000000000002101214' OR f2='1000000000002101214' OR f3='1000000000002101214')
```

And I need the result to show that the column name where the number is located is f1. So....

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please show us what did you try?

Comment: That is the thing..., I don't know what to try. MySQL wise, it is my understanding that to get the column names I need to ask the database_schema table, but I don't know if perl has a way to help.

Comment: Perl certainly can help you with this, but spoonfeeding is not allowed here, you'll have to show what have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Well, thanks, I guess..... I'll look elsewhere for help. Like I had said before I don't even know where to start. I'm new to Perl, but whatever. Thank you. At least I tried....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I don't even know where to start`

Check out [Perl's DBI module](http://dbi.perl.org/). Read the documentation. You'll have to do something like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use DBI;
 #Connect to your database, provide id, password
 my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:perltest','root','password') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 #Write your query
 my $sql = "select * from database_schema";
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 #Execute it
 $sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
 #Fetch the value
 while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
 #Do something with your result
    print "@row\n";
 }
```

If you are new to Perl then see: http://learn.perl.org/

**Edit:** Query to find out column name based on the value found in column.

```
Select 'f1'

from database_schema

where database_schema.f1 = 1000000000002101214 

union

Select 'f2'

from database_schema

where database_schema.f2 = 1000000000002101214 

union

Select 'f3'

from database_schema

where database_schema.f3 = 1000000000002101214
```

Comment: I will 'answer my own question' with a response to yours, I can't use markdown here and my response is a bit long.... THanks for the help!

Comment: You can use pastebin.

Comment: Yup, that does the trick! Thank you so much, and sorry for the 'newbie' errors.